# wordpress: create a search field (front end) to query API

Tags: wordpress, forms, security, search

I am creating a WP plugin that has a user front end page with a search box. The search string is going to query an API later:

```
<form action="" method="get">
   <?php  wp_nonce_field('action_search','field_search'); ?>
   <input type='text' name='search_input'/>
   <input type="submit" value="Search" />
</form>
```

I am not sure about the wp_nonce_field() which I use a lot in the plugin backend forms. But should I use it in the frontend...especially with method="get"? I adds a shit load of stuff to the url.
But it is recommended (?) because it finds out if the result page was queries from a different origin.

What do you think? With or without wp_nonce_field()?

Thanks,
Ben

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's just a search box, a nonce is not needed. You may or may not need the nonce later when querying the API, but for the front-end it doesn't matter. Since it is just a search, the form action is non-destructive and there's no need to protect the submission.